# KStream/KsqlDb application with Persistent State Store in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

1. Does anyone here have experience in deploying KStream/KsqlDb application with Persistent State Store in Kubernetes environment without loosing the auto scalability? i.e. Automatic creation of state store volume and the state for new container and rebalancing once the container is gone without loosing the topic partiton to the data volume mapping. Is it possible?
2. When a Persistent State store disappears(or gets deleted), will KStream restore the state store from the Change Log topic automatically or we have to manually reset the consumer offsets to earliest on the Change log topic consumer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This is hard to achieve. However, you could use standby tasks to get HA for this case.
2. You don't need to do anything. Kafka Streams will automatically restore state from the changelog.